How to use Uniform Boundedness Principle (UBP) to solve this problem?
Problem: Let  X  be a nvs(normed vector space), and let  $$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$$  with the property that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty | x^*(x_n)| < \infty, \quad \forall x^*\in X^*.$$
Prove that
$$\sup_{\|x^*\| \leq 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty | x^*(x_n)| < \infty.$$
My attempt：
To apply the Uniform Boundedness Principle (UBP), it needs to work in a Banach space. Observing that  X^*  is a Banach space, I consider the construction of the functional:
$$T_n : x^* \to \sum_{k=1}^n |x^*(x_n)| $$
However,  T_n  is sublinear, not linear. To apply the UBP, I need  T_n  to be a linear functional. Therefore, I consider to use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to extend  T_n  to a linear functional(on Bx*, i.e. unit ball of X*). Once the extension is obtained, I can then utilize the Uniform Boundedness Principle to complete the proof.
My question: Whether the above idea is feasible and if there is a better way to solve this problem?

For alternative solutions, you may want to see either of the first few results from this Approach$0$ search, since this problem has appeared many times before it seems. Nonetheless, I don't think you can apply Hahn-Banach to a sublinear function to my knowledge: you can use a sublinear functional to replace the norm condition iirc but the theorem still only creates linear extensions of already linear functionals.

Thank you for your reply. My idea is to use the Hahn-Banach theorem on Bx￼ so that the extension remains linear on Bx ￼, thereby allowing the use of the Uniform Boundedness Principle (UBP).

It can't become a linear functional since the values of $T_n$ for $x^\star$ and $-x^\star$ are equal instead of opposite. Hahn-Banach doesn't apply to a functional that is not already linear.
